# Wp_editor doesn't send the required data

Tags: php, front-end, wp-editor, wp-update-post

The `wp_editor` function is working fine concerning the displaying of editor and sending of information, except that the information is never sent as it is.

In a template file responsible of updating posts from front end, var_dumping always  shows differences betweeen the content coming from database and content sent by editor via POST variable, even the user changes nothing under the editor.

One of the problems for instance, is that the string sent by POST variable is containing `"\` instead of `"`.

In the website I am creating, I need to display the differences between the edits of a post using PEAR text_diff library. Application tells me that there is always difference between edits, even it is not the case, because even after `esc_attr`, and `strip_tags`, there are differences (double quotes for example).

Can you please give me an insight on how to resolve such issue? Are there any techniques to make wp_editor works right? Or should I code my own editor??

Thank you very much for your time and assistance.

Comment: Do you mean `\"` instead of `"\ ` ?  If so, have you tried using [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/stripslashes) on `wp_editor`'s output?

Comment: Thank you @PatJ for your feedback. It replaces double quotes `"` by `\"`.

Comment: [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/stripslashes) should translate `\"` to `"` for you.

Comment: Thank you sir I will do it and come back to give a feedback. :-)

Comment: Great, the function resolved my actual issue, now I have `POST`  variable content and result of `get_the_content` giving the same data after `strip_tags`, `esc_attr `(and `stripslashes` for POST). But I am still looking for a final fix for the `wp_editor` strange behaviour. Thanks sir

Comment: That's not "strange behaviour" on `wp_editor()`'s part -- that's part of escaping certain characters in order to safely insert strings into the database, etc. See [Data Validation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation), for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making this an answer so that others can find it:

PHP's native function [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/stripslashes) will translate `\"` back to `"` (as well as removing the backslash character from other escaped characters, and changing `\\` into `\`).